# boost asio set_verify_callback leaks shared_ptr

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, memory-leaks, boost-asio

I'm seeing a leak when using set_verify_callback on an ssl socket. I have a class "CClientSock" with  member "boost::asio::ssl::stream m_socket;"

My CClientSock class derives from 'enable_shared_from_this

```
    class CClientSock : public boost::enable_shared_from_this
```

If I call:

```
    m_socket.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&CClientSock::verify_certificate, 
        shared_from_this(),
        _1, 
        _2));
```

then my CClientSock instance is never destroyed.

If I do not call the "m_socket.set_verify_callback" then my CClientSock instance is destroyed correctly.

The code looks like this:

```
    void CClientSock::StartPoll()
    {
    m_socket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer | 
        boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);

    m_socket.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&CClientSock::verify_certificate, 
        shared_from_this(),
        _1, 
        _2));


    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator;
    endpoint_iterator = ResolveAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", nPort);

    boost::asio::async_connect(
        m_socket.lowest_layer(), 
        endpoint_iterator,
        boost::bind(&CClientSock::handle_connect, 
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    bool CClientSock::verify_certificate(
        bool preverified,
        boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx
    )
    {
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);
    CString s;
    s.Format("%02d SSL Verify: %s", m_nId, subject_name);
    LogMsg(m_dwThreadId, &st, s, 0, NULL);

    return preverified;
    }
```

Is there something that has to be done in "set_verify_callback" to release a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclical reference by retaining a `shared_ptr<CClientSock>` in the verify callback. The context maintains a [`boost::asio::ssl::detail::verify_callback`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/e818f88f9560949d9888d48b988c9c68f6dace46/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/verify_callback.hpp) member, which contains your shared pointer. To break the cycle, use a weak pointer with a lambda

```
std::weak_ptr<CClientSock> weak( shared_from_this() );
m_socket.set_verify_callback([weak](bool p, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& context) {
    std::shared_ptr<CClientSock> strong( weak );
    if ( strong ) {
        strong->verify_certificate( p, context );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam - I tried this but can't get it to compile using various capture modes ([], [&], [=]). I see various forms of: "error C3493: 'weak' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified".  I'm not too familiar with lambdas so there may be other options available. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Ken needed to explicitly capture the `weak_ptr` in the lambda, answer has been updated

Answer (score 2):

After responses from sehe and Sam Miller, I got this to work. I ended up using most of the code shown by Sam, using the 'shared pointer cycle' idea first posted by sehe.

I modified the lambda expression to use the 'by value' capture clause ([=]). This told the compiler how to handle the weak_ptr variable. Then I modified the expression for a function returning a boolean. I ended up with this, which does allow the object instance to be destroyed.

```
    boost::weak_ptr weak( shared_from_this() );
    m_socket.set_verify_callback([=](bool p, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& context)->bool {
        boost::shared_ptr strong(weak);
        if ( strong ) {
            p = strong->verify_certificate(p, context);
        }
        return p;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that the SSL context might be re-used.

In that case, you could explicitly manage the context, so you know when it gets destroyed:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_verify_callback.html

Or, there could be a shared pointer cycle created by the context holding on to the socket such that none of context or handler get released. (In that case you should be seeing more issues). Try breaking the cycle by explicitly releasing the handler:

```
s.set_verify_callback([](bool p, verify_context&) { return p; });
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't fully understand how to use your example. Could you show how that would be implemented in the context of my example?

Comment: You will have to be patient though, as I will be at work the rest of the evening as well :)